# I created the code using mysqli_fetch_assoc with 'while' , but it's not woking

Tags: php, mysqli

I created the code using mysqli_fetch_assoc with 'while' as shown below.
But it does not work.

> if ($ result = mysqli_query ($ dbconn, $ query)) {
>   It works by here.
>
> while ($ row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($ result)) {
>   It does not work from here.

I can not find the wrong part.
If I do not use 'while', it works as follows.

What is the problem?

```html
// not works
$query = "select * from member where f_status='1'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($dbconn, $query)) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row[f_status]==0) {
   error("No data");
  } else {
   echo $row[f_user_id];
   echo $row[f_user_name];
  }
 }
 mysqli_free_result($result);
}



// works
$query = "select * from member where f_status='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row) {
 echo $row[f_user_id];
 echo $row[f_user_name];
} else {
 error("No data");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you have iterated while loop and condition to show `No data` message,

You should try this way:

```
$query = "select * from member where f_status='1'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query)) {
    if ($result->num_rows) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row[f_user_id];
            echo $row[f_user_name];
        }
    }
    else {
        error("No data");
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Hope this should solve your issue.